# Issue with PL/SQL Procedure to upload CSV with more than 45 columns in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to enable the user to upload a CSV file with more than 45 columns into my Oracle APEX application, so I am unable to use the Data Load Wizard functionality. I found the following thread on how to do this with a solution by ZKay: https://community.oracle.com/message/9316828#9316828. I have created a file browse item and attached the following PL/SQL procedure to a button that I want to import the file into the EMP table as described below. However, I am getting the following error:

**ORA-06550: line 29, column 15: PLS-00201: identifier 'HEX_TO_DECIMAL' must be declared ORA-06550: line 29, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

PL/SQL Process:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
v_blob_data BLOB;
v_blob_len NUMBER;
v_position NUMBER;
v_raw_chunk RAW(10000);
v_char CHAR(1);
c_chunk_len number := 1;
v_line VARCHAR2 (32767) := NULL;
v_data_array wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;
v_rows number;
v_sr_no number := 1;
v_rows_loaded NUMBER;

BEGIN

-- Read data from wwv_flow_files</span>
select blob_content into v_blob_data
from wwv_flow_files
where last_updated = (select max(last_updated) from wwv_flow_files where UPDATED_BY = :APP_USER)
and id = (select max(id) from wwv_flow_files where updated_by = :APP_USER);

v_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_data);
v_position := 1;

-- Read and convert binary to char</span>
WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len ) LOOP
v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position);
v_char := chr(hex_to_decimal(rawtohex(v_raw_chunk)));
v_line := v_line || v_char;
v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;
-- When a whole line is retrieved </span>
IF v_char = CHR(10) THEN
-- Convert comma to : to use wwv_flow_utilities </span>
v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ',', ':');
-- Convert each column separated by : into array of data </span>
v_data_array := wwv_flow_utilities.string_to_table (v_line);
--DELETE OLD DATA
-- Insert data into target table </span>
IF v_sr_no >1 THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO EMP(EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO)
VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4)'
USING
-- v_sr_no,
v_data_array(1),
v_data_array(2),
v_data_array(3),
v_data_array(4);
END IF;
-- Clear out
v_line := NULL;
v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1;
END IF;
END LOOP;

END;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Have you considered apex_data_parser package, which supports 300 columns? https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex_data_parser-package

Comment: @Scott  - I am in APEX 5.1.3, and I believe that apex_data_parser was rolled out for 19.1. Is there a way to find the source code for that function?

Comment: given the version your can re-engineer https://github.com/antonscheffer/excel2collections to use your own table, instead of APEX collections.